# How to change color of multiple objects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have multiple triangle objects in white and I want to change it to yellow. Can you show me how to change colors without switching them one by one ? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Create a [Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Materials.html) and assign a yellow colour to it and assign this material to each triangle or simply use the existing material of the triangle and assign a yellow colour to it.

Comment: @nIcEcOw I mean I want to find a way to do it in one time because there are 40 triangles so I have to do 40 times.

Comment: When you change colour of the material, all triangles using the same material will get affected in one go.

Comment: I'll explain the answer here a little bit. When you create an object you can set it to have a material, which can modify its color. You can create a material for your objects to reference. When you change the color of the material, it will change the color of all objects using that material.

Comment: When adding the Material, you can select all object at the same time and just drag n' drop it once.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now. Also just because you use a certain IDE (`visual-studio`) doesn't automatically mean your question is primarily about that IDE.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, right-click on the project tab and then create>material. Then go to the albedo's color button and then select the color you wanna choose. Then select all of your triangles and drag and drop in the newly created material on the very bottom of the selected triangles.

**NOTE: If any of your triangles is a prefab, like the very first triangle as per the provided image, right click on it then prefab then unpack completely. then you will be able to drag in the material.**

I hope it was helpful to you!!

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same material to all of them and you'll be able to change the colour of all the objects just by changing it on that material. You can quickly assign the material to all of them by selecting all of the objects and dragging the material into the "Materials" field of the renderer.